# Python, complicated file iteration?

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over an infile, create an outfile that is same as the infile at this point. Then I want to iterate over reference file and add TER records to the correct line when needed. The problem is that I have many of the same numbers in the outfile and need to add the TER record to the very last one. (In real life the reference file has different numbers after at the end that I need to preserve.

```
import sys
import argparse

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add TER records')
    parser.add_argument('infile', help='input file (PDB format)')
    parser.add_argument('outfile', help='output file (PDB format)')
    parser.add_argument('reference', help =' ref')
    args = parser.parse_args()

   residues = []
   x = 0


  with open(args.infile, "r") as f, open(args.outfile, "w+") as of,open(args.reference,"r") as rf:
    for line in f:
        of.write(line)
        for line in rf:
            if line[0:3]== "TER":
                resnum = line[22:27]
                resnum_1 = int(resnum)
                residues.append(resnum_1)
    of.seek(0)
    for line in of:
        if line [0:4]== "ATOM":
            res = line[22:27]
            res_2 = int(res)
            for x in residues:
                if x == res_2 and res_2+1 == x+1:
                    of.write("TER\n")
                    x = 0
                else:
                    continue


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

My infile:

```
ATOM      1  N   GLU D 384      51.765  39.857  23.514  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  H1  GLU D 384      50.823  39.839  23.150  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      3  H2  GLU D 384      51.956  39.044  24.081  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      4  H3  GLU D 384      52.469  39.840  22.790  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      5  CA  GLU D 384      51.934  41.135  24.345  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  HA  GLU D 384      53.002  41.062  24.550  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      7  CB  GLU D 384      51.712  42.439  23.503  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      8  HB2 GLU D 384      52.307  42.297  22.600  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9  HB3 GLU D 384      50.640  42.356  23.323  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10  CG  GLU D 384      52.024  43.786  24.125  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     11  HG2 GLU D 384      52.138  44.557  23.363  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     12  HG3 GLU D 384      51.201  44.086  24.773  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     13  CD  GLU D 384      53.381  43.828  24.935  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     14  OE1 GLU D 384      53.634  43.069  25.869  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     15  OE2 GLU D 384      54.142  44.711  24.602  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     16  C   GLU D 384      51.078  41.093  25.570  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     17  O   GLU D 384      49.819  41.006  25.499  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     18  N   THR D 385      51.596  41.332  26.746  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     19  H   THR D 385      52.606  41.355  26.728  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     20  CA  THR D 385      50.815  41.615  27.982  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     21  HA  THR D 385      49.834  41.932  27.628  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     22  CB  THR D 385      50.763  40.416  28.984  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     23  HB  THR D 385      50.235  40.697  29.895  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     24  CG2 THR D 385      50.195  39.154  28.283  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     25 HG21 THR D 385      49.322  39.526  27.747  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     26 HG22 THR D 385      50.838  38.704  27.527  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     27 HG23 THR D 385      49.834  38.399  28.981  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     28  OG1 THR D 385      52.133  40.236  29.373  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     29  HG1 THR D 385      52.186  40.766  30.172  1.00  0.00
```

My reference (and the way the outfile TER records should look like:

```
ATOM      1  N   GLU D 384      51.765  39.857  23.514  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  H1  GLU D 384      50.823  39.839  23.150  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      3  H2  GLU D 384      51.956  39.044  24.081  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      4  H3  GLU D 384      52.469  39.840  22.790  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      5  CA  GLU D 384      51.934  41.135  24.345  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  HA  GLU D 384      53.002  41.062  24.550  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      7  CB  GLU D 384      51.712  42.439  23.503  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      8  HB2 GLU D 384      52.307  42.297  22.600  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9  HB3 GLU D 384      50.640  42.356  23.323  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10  CG  GLU D 384      52.024  43.786  24.125  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     11  HG2 GLU D 384      52.138  44.557  23.363  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     12  HG3 GLU D 384      51.201  44.086  24.773  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     13  CD  GLU D 384      53.381  43.828  24.935  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     14  OE1 GLU D 384      53.634  43.069  25.869  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     15  OE2 GLU D 384      54.142  44.711  24.602  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     16  C   GLU D 384      51.078  41.093  25.570  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     17  O   GLU D 384      49.819  41.006  25.499  1.00  0.00           O  
TER

ATOM     18  N   THR D 385      51.596  41.332  26.746  1.00  0.00           N
```

What I get however is this:

```
ATOM     96  HA  SER D 391      45.358  52.899  33.158  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     97  CB  SER D 391      45.963  51.960  31.364  1.00  0.00           C  
TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

TER

 1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM    100  OG  SER D 391      45.205  52.828  30.574  1.00  0.00           O
```

Can anybody help? I am new to programming as you can see:)

Comment: If you want to first copy and infile to an outfile, you can just call `outfile = shutil.copyfile(<infile>)' (https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).

Comment: `of.write()` does not insert characters, it overwrites them.

Comment: Adam: That is not my problem, that part of the code works fine.

Comment: Kevin: Good to know. But what I am trying to figure out first is why is overwritten in a completely wrong place

Comment: When I try to run this, it dies for lack of a resnum on the TER line.

Comment: It was the way this was edited, there is a resnum on the TER line. Exactly where the other resnum is. Thank you.